# how to access model's field in onclick event(django)

Tags: python, django

I'm not a English user so my English will not be good.

I'm learning django.

I want to access model's field when I click button in the template.

this is the related part from the template.

```
<button type="button" onclick="{% post.like+=1 %}">1따봉!</button> 추천 수 : {{ post.like }}
```

when I click the button I want the like count to be increased by one.

How can ı achieve this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or core Javascript?

Comment: I can use jQuery and Javascript, but now I'm not using them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do this easier

```
<button id="buttonLike" data-like="{{ post.like }}" type="button">{{ post.like }}</button>
$(function() {
        $('#buttonLike').on('click', function() {
            var val = parseInt($(this).data('like'));
            val += 1;
            $(this).data('like', val);
            $(this).val(val);
            // Do some ajax operations to update the django model
        });
    });
```